# How to get value of combobox from a function in tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

I have create a function to display a new combobox when function is called. But i am unable to get the value of the selected combobox.

```
def drist(id):
    url = f"https://cdn-api.co-vin.in/api/v2/admin/location/districts/{id}"
    headers = {
        "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:89.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/89.0"}
    response = requests.request("GET", url, headers=headers)
    data = response.json()
    dist_name = [i['district_name'] for i in data['districts']]
    ds = tuple(dist_name)
    dris = StringVar()
    dist_ch = ttk.Combobox(window, width=27, textvariable=dris)
    dist_ch['values'] = ds  
    dist_ch.place(x=650, y=30) 
    dist_ch.bind("<<ComboboxSelected>>", clicked_dis)
    


def clicked_dis(event):
    print(dist_ch.get())
```

How can i get the value of combobox?

Comment: Try adding `global dris` at the start of your `drist` function. Then you can use `dris.get()` inside your `clicked_dis` function

Comment: getting the error NameError: name 'dris' is not defined

Comment: Use `print(event.widget.get())`, inside `clicked_dis()`

Answer (score 0):

You can get the value of text by one of three methods.

Example code

```py
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk

def selection(event):
    # Three methods here all get the same value.
    print(event.widget.get())
    print(combo.get())
    print(combo_var.get())

root = Tk()

values = ['USA', 'CANADA', 'JAPAN', 'KOREA', 'CHINA']
combo_var = StringVar()

combo = ttk.Combobox(root, values=values, textvariable=combo_var)
combo.pack()
combo.bind("<<ComboboxSelected>>",  selection)

root.mainloop()
```